# How do I get the first two closest numbers to a target from an array using lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm new to lodash and just getting the feel for functional programming with javascript. I'm using lodash 3.0.0-pre.

I have an array of numbers that are in order and a target number.

I need an array with the first and second closest numbers unless it was the last number then I just need it. How do I get that using lodash?

I found:

```
function getClosest(array, target) {
    var tuples = _.map(array, function(val) {
        return [val, Math.abs(val - target)];
    });
    return _.reduce(tuples, function(memo, val) {
        return (memo[1] < val[1]) ? memo : val;
    }, [-1, 999])[0];
}
```

I could change it to give me the closest two instead of one but I believe it will sequence through the entire array instead of just stopping once it has the two numbers it needs since it can stop when the difference in numbers starts to increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not to use `lodash` looping functions here if you care about performance.
As soon as you array is ordered - it's good to use a modified version of [Binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find index of the closest value:

```
function closestIndex(arr, target) {
    var i = 0, j = arr.length - 1, k;   

    while (i <= j) {
       k = Math.floor((i+j) / 2);
       if (target === arr[k] || Math.abs(i - j) <= 1 ) {
           return k;
       } else if (target < arr[k]) {
           j = k-1;
       } else {
           i = k+1;
       }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

and then simply compare adjacent elements in the array:

```
if (_.isNumber(arr[closestIndex - 1]) && _.isNumber(arr[closestIndex + 1])) {
    if (Math.abs(target - arr[closestIndex - 1]) < Math.abs(target - arr[closestIndex + 1])) {
        result.push(arr[closestIndex - 1]);
    } else {
        result.push(arr[closestIndex + 1]);
    }
}
```

See full example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lepe1nbL/).

Comment: Can you provide some info on why not to use lodash for looping?

Comment: @CalebKester, just not to iterate over the whole array as items inside are already sorted. Binary search works for `O(log n)` which is faster than `_.map` + `_.reduce`

Answer (score 0):

Not really a lodash task because it's not an easy n -> n or n -> 1 transformation. Additionally lodash doesn't allow you to cancel a statement early.

Anyway here's a solution:

```
var array= [2, 3, 5, 25, 135, 250, 300];

function getClosest(array, target) {
    var tuples = _.map(array, function(val) {
        return [val, Math.abs(val - target)];
    });

    var prev= [0, Number.MAX_VALUE];
    for(var i=0; i<tuples.length; i++){
        if(tuples[i][1] < prev[1]){
            prev= tuples[i];
        }else{
            if(i<2 || tuples[i][1] < tuples[i-2][1]){
                return [prev[0], tuples[i][0]];
            }else{
                return [prev[0], tuples[i-2][0]];
            }
        }
    }
    return [prev[0]];
}

console.log(getClosest(array, 3));
```

Could be optimized by finding the nearest element with Newton's method and then looking at elements before and after that. (If you have like 50000 numbers in your array ^^)

Comment: _Additionally lodash doesn't allow you to cancel a statement early_ - actually, `lodash` allows to interrupt several loops (like `_.forEach()`). Simply return `false` from your callback. See [docs](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach).

Comment: Oh right, good point - sadly only with forIn, forEach, forOwn and transform. And using forEach is pretty much only syntactic sugar anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your array is sorted and `arr[0] ≤ target`:

```
var getClosests =  function (arr, target) {
  var last = _.last(arr)
  if (target > last) {
    return [last];
  }
  var index = _.findIndex(arr, function(a) { return target - a <= 0 });
  neighbours = [arr[index-1], arr[index], arr[index+1]]
  return _.chain(neighbours).sortBy(function(a) { 
    return Math.abs( a - target) })
  .take(2).value()
}

getClosests([2, 3, 5, 25, 135, 250, 300], 100);
getClosests([2, 3, 5, 25, 135, 250, 300], 25);
getClosests([2, 3, 5, 25, 135, 250, 300], 400);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Find two Closet to given Goal in Array:** (without Lodash)

```js
function findCloset(givenList, goal) {
  var first;
  var second;
  var finalCollection = [givenList[0], givenList[1]];
  givenList.forEach((item, firtIndex) => {
    first = item;

    for (let i = firtIndex + 1; i < givenList.length; i++) {
      second = givenList[i];

      if (first + second < goal) {
        if (first + second > finalCollection[0] + finalCollection[1]) {
          finalCollection = [first, second];
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return finalCollection;
}

var counts = [2, 42, 82, 329, 122, 40, 162, 202, 3, 5, 242, 282, 322, 35, 362];
var goal = 80;
console.log(findCloset(counts, goal));
```